# Image uploading issue with Carrierwave and Minimagick (Ruby on rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, image-processing, carrierwave, minimagick

I am using Carrierwave to upload images and that works fine but I am now trying to use Minimagick  to process these uploaded images.

**What is going on?**

The images still upload as well as their thumb version, however both images are exactly the same size.

Here is the uploader code:

```
class FileUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base

  include CarrierWave::MiniMagick

  # Choose what kind of storage to use for this uploader:
  storage :file

  # Override the directory where uploaded files will be stored.
  def store_dir
    "uploads/#{model.class.to_s.underscore}/#{mounted_as}/#{model.id}"
  end

  # Create different versions of your uploaded files:
  version :thumb do
    process :resize_to_fit => [100, 100]
  end

  # Add a white list of extensions which are allowed to be uploaded.
  def extension_white_list
    %w(jpg jpeg gif png)
  end

end
```

And here is how I am calling it:

```
 <%= image_tag example.my_file.url(:thumb).to_s %>
```

I dont think it is anything to do with the way I am calling it because the two files created by all this are the same, so sound slike its to do with processing it on upload.

Here is the folder created for each object:
[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2yQrN.png)

**--- Fixed ---**

The issue was ImageMagick. It was not properly configured on my machine so that means no gem that deals with image processing (Paperclip, Minimagick or Dragonfly) could complete any image manipulation.

Comment: did you try `resize_to_fill` ?

Comment: Yes and it does not seem to change t in any way. Any idea as to why no resizing of any sort is working?

Comment: Do you have all required gems installed ?

Comment: Yes and have ran bundle install too.